# What is mean Callbacks "hard to read and harder to reason"

Tags: multithreading, callback

in the article " Multi-threading and callbacks 
What is meant by section?

> Code that heavily uses callbacks can become hard to read and harder to
>   reason about.

[Multi-threading & callbacks primer](https://developer.android.com/courses/extras/multithreading#callbacks)

Comment: Don't edit questions to invalidate reasonable answers. Post a new question. I have rolled back your edit. [ask] [help] Use text, not images or links, for what can be given in text, including tables & the DDL of ERDs. Include everything needed to ask in your post, not at a link. When you are stuck explain why. Act on comments.

Answer (score 0):

(this is probably opinion based, but...):

1)  hard to read :   People conventionally read sequentially, whether it is prose, proofs or code.   Experiments with re-arranging stories have not yielded improved reading comprehension.  In code,  this:

```
while condition is not true
    wait for event
perform condition handling
```

is more readable than

```
on event do event_handler
....
event_handler:
    if condition is true
        perform condition handling
```

despite the latter idiom's history including FORTRAN, PL/1, BASIC and UNIX signals.
I am sure there are myriad theories about cognition that google would provide if you ask her nicely.

2) Harder to reason: here, reason assumes mechanical tools.  In the former example above, the handling of the condition is performed within the context of the actor (thread, process, ...) that waited for it.  That actor may be carrying important context for handling the condition, such as locks and exception handlers.   For example, imagine that the code for handling the condition could raise an exception.   Is it necessarily true that the same actors which setup the handler is the one handling it?   In a system like libdispatch, that is not the case, but sometimes is.  Does your testing capture both possibilities?

Without a deep introspection of both the mechanism to dispatch events and the event handling code it is difficult to determine what dependencies flow across that dispatch boundary.  Without access to all of the application, framework, operating system and even compiler source, it may be impossible.  Perhaps this is a good advert for open source.

But...
These apply to traditional sequential programs (1000s of lines of FORTRAN).  If you constructed your program conform to a formal construct, such as a state machine or push down automata, you could specify your program within a formal language (eg. yacc).
This makes it considerably easier to understand and reason about.

I wouldn't literally suggest yacc; but any formal system would insist on managing the state machine(s), so your program would exist entirely as a set of callouts invoked as transitions were realized.

Comment: Thank you for the answer